# Перенос HTML сайта на Wordpress

Tags: html, wordpress, css, php

Люди подскажите пожалуйсто как перенести сверстанный сайт на CMS Wordpress.Какие основные этапы надо пройти. Как бы сверстанную страницу я всунул в WP как тему. Но как подключить к этой странице функции для управления из админки. Что бы контент можно было редактировать.
???????

Comment: Вот так в двух словах вряд ли вам кто то объяснит, прочтите, например, [этот](http://www.presswordpress.ru/wordpress-themes/wordpress-themes-create/) мануал для начала.

Answer (score 2):

1. Скопируйте контент своего сайта
2. Удалите свой "html-сайт"
3. Установите вордпресс
4. Установите нужный шаблон
5. Немного "обработайте напильником" шаблон WP, чтобы он вам больше нравился
6. Создайте структуру и разместите сохранённый контент из админки WP